# How do i host WCF service in windows service?

Tags: wcf

I am trying to host WCF serviec in managed Windows Service. Basically i have 1 solution CustomersWCFLibrary which contains 3 Projects.

1) CustomersWCFLibrary :-

This is my app.config :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CustomersWCFLibrary.Properties.Settings.NorthWindConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service  name="CustomersWCFLibrary.CustomersService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint  address="net.tcp://localhost:9000/CustomersService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="CustomersWCFLibrary.ICustomersService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9001/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

My class :-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;

namespace CustomersWCFLibrary
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
    public class CustomersService : ICustomersService
    {
        public List<Customers> GetAllCustomers()
        {
            List<Customers> customersList = new List<Customers>();
            using (SqlConnection objSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.NorthWindConnectionString))
            {
                objSqlConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand objSqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select CustomerID, ContactName, ContactTitle,CompanyName,Address from Customers",objSqlConnection);
                SqlDataReader objSqlDataReader =  objSqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (objSqlDataReader.Read())
                {
                    string customerID = objSqlDataReader.GetString(0);
                    string contactName = objSqlDataReader.GetString(1);
                    string contactTitle = objSqlDataReader.GetString(2);
                    string companyName = objSqlDataReader.GetString(3);
                    string Address = objSqlDataReader.GetString(4);
                    Customers objCustomers = new Customers();
                    objCustomers.CustomerId = customerID;
                    objCustomers.ContactName = contactName;
                    objCustomers.ContactTitle = contactTitle;
                    objCustomers.CompanyName = companyName;
                    objCustomers.Address = Address;

                    customersList.Add(objCustomers);
                }
            }
            return customersList;
        }
    }
}
```

My contract :-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace CustomersWCFLibrary
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICustomersService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<Customers> GetAllCustomers();


        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }

    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations
    [DataContract]
    public class Customers
    {

        [DataMember]
        public string CustomerId
        { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string ContactName
        {get; set;}

         [DataMember]
        public string ContactTitle
        {get; set;}

         [DataMember]
        public string CompanyName
        {get; set;}

         [DataMember]
        public string Address
        {get; set;}


    }
}
```

2) CustomersWindowsService

App.config :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="CustomersWCFLibrary.CustomersService">

                <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9000/CustomersService" 
                          binding="netTcpBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="" name="CustomersService_Tcp" contract="CustomersWCFLibrary.ICustomersService" />

            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

This is my code of windows service :-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace CustomersWindowsService
{
    public partial class CustomersServiceWinService : ServiceBase
    {

        private ServiceHost host = null;

        public CustomersServiceWinService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

                host = new ServiceHost(typeof(CustomersWCFLibrary.CustomersService));
                host.Open();

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            host.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

3) My Console Application WCFCustomersTest

App.Config :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings />
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9000/CustomersService"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="CustomersWCFLibrary.ICustomersService"
                name="CustomersService_Tcp" kind="" endpointConfiguration="" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;


namespace WCFCustomersTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var channel = new ChannelFactory<CustomersWCFLibrary.ICustomersService>("CustomersService_Tcp").CreateChannel();
            List<CustomersWCFLibrary.Customers> objList = channel.GetAllCustomers();
            Console.Write(objList.Count);
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

My console application contains reference to my WCFClassLibrary(1st Project).

1) If i do not start my Windows Service and run it in VS 2010, i get the proper output . But if i run my application from outside the VS, i get a very long strange exception.

2) If i start my Windows Service and i try to run my application from within VS or outside VS i get this error :-

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException was unhandled
  Message=The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.
  Source=mscorlib
  Action=http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher/fault
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at CustomersWCFLibrary.ICustomersService.GetAllCustomers()
       at WCFCustomersTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\abc\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\CustomersWCFLibrary\WCFCustomersTest\Program.cs:line 15
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

I am trying to solve this mistake since 3 hours without any success.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you sure that's all the code????  ;P

Comment: I suggest that your windows service is not able to connect to DB. Turn on WCF tracing - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka, There is no problem with DB connection.

Comment: @leppie and @hydrogen :- Sorry, i didn't want to confuse you with too much of code. But i believe every single line of the post i made is necessary ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest two things for troubleshoting the issue,

1. Enable includeExceptionDetailInFaults, to get more details on the response.
2. Enable the WCF tracing, as you probably will find more details in the trace.

I will able to help more if I can see more details about the error. That error you posted there, is a generic one.

Thanks
Pablo.

Comment: I know this is a little late coming, but it's worth noting - if you turn on tracing, only use it for debugging purposes.  Be sure to turn it off in production, because it uses a pretty fair amount of resources and will slow your service down.

Answer (score 1):

Tun on exceptions details here: <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />

or debug coming request on managed windows service side to see what fault is happening there.